# What is the difference between standard class files and contributed class files?

Tags: packages

How to distinguish one of them from the other? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Usually by name and/or by purpose.  Only half-joking, too, see the [al­ter­na­tive LaTeX class(es)](https://www.ctan.org/topic/class) on CTAN if you are interested in more than the base `.cls` files (notably: `article.cls`, `letter.cls`, `report.cls`, `book.cls` -- though there are others).

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official documentation file `clsguide`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide?lang=en), standard classes include a line like

```
\ProvidesClass{article}[1994/06/01 Standard LaTeX class]
```

which prints `1994/06/01 Standard LaTeX class` in the `.log` file (the current version is actually `2014/09/29 v1.4h`).  The important part is the phrase "Standard LaTeX", since the `clsguide` documentations also states

> The phrase Standard LaTeX must not be used in the identification banner of any file other than those in the standard LATEX distribution.

You will find the standard classes in the base directory of your distribution `...texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`.  For `texlive` 2016 this contains

```
article.cls letter.cls  ltxdoc.cls  minimal.cls report.cls
book.cls    ltnews.cls  ltxguide.cls    proc.cls    slides.cls
```

all of which are labelled as `Standard LaTeX`.

Comment: I didn't check, but it seems the clsguide needs updating.

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can't check since i am on my phone, but didnt the standard classes get an update in 2014?

Comment: @Johannes_B The date was not meant to be specific, just an example of the type of line.  Answer reworded.